# What is most effective and easy way to batch INSERT query into SQL 2005/8

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ado.net, insert

I'm new to `ADO.NET` so asking for help. I have to insert large number of records in one table.

What is best-practice, effective and easy way to do that? I found an article called [Batch Requests (ADO.NET Data Services Framework)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668802.aspx) but it isn't clear for me.

Also I found an article about [BULK INSERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx) but such method uses external file, I don't want to use it because of having an `ASP.NET` application.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look at the [SqlBulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx) class. Also it sounds obvious, but not everyone knows this- you can significantly speed up insert performance by using transactions- [I've blogged about this before](http://richardod.blogspot.com/2009/03/speeding-up-sql-server-inserts-by-using.html).